# mysql join on date where one table's date is a month before

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables of which I want to join on the date. While the date are of the same format, I want to join `t1.date_1` to `t2.date_2` but where `t2.date_2` is a month before. Please see my query below for context and the output I want:

```
t1
date_1      count_t1
2015-01-01   10
2015-02-01   20
2015-03-01   30



t2
date_2      count_t2
2014-12-01   40
2015-01-01   50
2015-02-01   60
2015-03-01   70

output i want:
date_1       percent_before
2015-01-01    0.25            <--10/40
2015-02-01    0.40            <--20/50
2015-03-01    0.5             <--30/60

my query:
select (t1.count_1/t2.count_2) as percent_before
from table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.date_1 = (t2.date_2 - 1 month);
```

Comment: my error: `Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval. 
Error Code: 5407`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `interval` keyword:

```
select t1.date_1, (t1.count_1 / t2.count_2) as percent_before
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date_1 = (t2.date_2 - interval 1 month);
```

Answer (score 0):

For people using teradata and cannot use interval:

```
select t1.date_1, (t1.count_1 / t2.count_2) as percent_before
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date_1 = add_months(t2.date_2 - 1 month);
```